# Infinite loop of zero in table

Tags: c++

this code is dividing a circle into X part and display a table of radian value of each part.
but
I get an infinite loop of 0 display when I'm using value superior to 6
with value under 6 I get '0 1 2 3 4 5 6'
It seems that displayed value are not float either.
I have the code using degrees and work fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


#define pi 3.14159265359
#define pi2 6.28318530718

int nbObjets = 0;

void objetsPositionRadian(int tab[], int nbObjets);


int main(){

    int tabRadian[] = {0};
    
    std::cout << "Nombre d'objets ? ";
    std::cin >> nbObjets;

    objetsPositionRadian(tabRadian, nbObjets);

    return 0;
}

void objetsPositionRadian(int tab[], int nbObjets){
    float radian = (360/nbObjets) * (pi/180);
    for (int i = 0; i < pi2; i+=radian){
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: `i+=radian` is adding `float` less than 1 to `int`, that won't do anything.

Comment: thank you that was my mistake, works fine now

Comment: You have the same basic problem in another place. If you ask for more than 360 objects, `(360 / nbObjets)` is going to become zero, and you'll get an infinite loop again. Changing `360` to `360.0` should fix that one.

Comment: Regardless if it works "fine", the `for` loop should be using integers, not floating point as the start / continue / stop conditions.   The reason is that your loop will not be guaranteed to loop the number of times you expect it to if you use floating point loop variables.  If you need to loop `n` times, then `i` should go from `0` to `n`, and inside the loop, scale the `i` value to the float you want to use.

Comment: Working in degrees is nice, because 360 divides evenly by so many different integers.

Comment: @MarkRansom this is just a part of my code, I displaying in degrees and in radian. the next step is to display the x / y coordinates of each point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious move here is to change `i` in your loop to be a `double` (or `float`) instead of an `int`.

Along with that, when computing `radian`, `360/nbObjets` does integer division, so if `nbObjets` is > 360, it'll give a result of 0. Changing `360` to `360.0` fixes that problem.

But that leaves another problem: depending on the vagaries of floating point math, if you ask for a lot of objects, there's a good change you'll end up computing positions for one more object than you asked for (and conceivably even more than that if you asked for a really large number of objects).

This problem arises from cumulative errors as you add `radian` to `i` in the loop. Rather than doing that, you almost certain want something on this order:

```cpp
for (int i=0; i<nbObjets; i++)
    cout << i * radian;
```

This way, you always get exactly the number of objects you asked for, and any possible errors in the value don't accumulate from one iteration to the next.

Comment: your solution seems to be more stable with the problem of float, is double not giving enough precision too ?

Comment: @CTRL-Z: depending on the number of objects, just using `double` may suffice. Offhand, I'm a bit uncertain exactly how many objects you could have before it would go wrong.

Comment: now that I'm aware of this unstable situation I think your solution is the best solution.

Comment: @CTRL-Z: Surely.

Comment: @CTRL-Z `double` has more precision than `float` so it's almost always the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two dangerous things in the following two lines:

```
    float radian = (360/nbObjets) * (pi/180);
    for (int i = 0; i < pi2; i+=radian)
```

First: `nbObject` is defined as an integer. As a result `360/nbObjects` will be calculated as an integer (e.g. for 7, the result will be 51, not a floating point number).

Next, you define `i` as an integer. When you add a number to it which is smaller than 1, it will always remain the same.

Therefore I advise you to use more floating point numbers when needed, as in this proposal:

```
    double radian = ((double)360/nbObjets) * (pi/180); // first typecast 360 as a
                                                       // floating point, in order 
                                                       // to enforce floating 
                                                       // point arithmetic.
    for (double i = 0; i < pi2; i+=radian)
```

This should work better.

Comment: This suffers from the condition mentioned in the comments.  There is no guarantee that the loop will always loop the same number of times, due to floating point not being exact.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: It should always loop the same number of times each run. Floating points are deterministic, just... not intuitive.  Oh, did you mean looping the same number of times as it did before? That's true

Comment: @MooingDuck: In this case, I'd say the important point is that the number of results you get may not match the number of objects you asked it to compute positions for.

Comment: @MooingDuck A change of compiler / compiler options could render different results in terms of how many iterations are being done.

Comment: thank you for your help, I was searching in the wrong direction.